# Search and replace a string ([TableName].[ColumnName]) in a SQL query

Tags: c#, regex

I am parsing a SQL query and converting them to a domain-specific language. For this I am using Regex pattern match.

For e.g. if there is match like `TableName.ColumnName` (e.g. `Customer.RecordNumber`), then I need to replace this string with a `$1*`, if there is another column (e.g. `Customer.Forename`), then `$2*` and so on.

This is my code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> FieldsUsed = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string[] words = sql.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int x = 1;

string regPattern = "^" + TableAlias + ".\\w+$";

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i)
{
    string word = words[i];
    Regex regex = new Regex(regPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    Match match = regex.Match(word);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        string fldNo = "$" + x.ToString() + "*";

        if (!FieldsUsed.ContainsKey(match.Value))
        {
            FieldsUsed.Add(match.Value, fldNo);
            words[i] = fldNo;
            ++x;
        }
    }
}
```

This matches where there is an exact match, but when there is an expression like `ISNULL(TableName.ColumnName, '')`, then the Regex fails.

Could anyone please point the correct Regex which would extract the required value (i.e. TableName.FieldName) from both the scenarios above?

Comment: are you aware that this approach is doomed to fail if you allow any valid SQL query as input? in this case, anything but a full AST (parser) won't do. What about string literals, text in comments, row source aliases instead of table names, CTEs, ...?

Comment: @RandRandom: well, relational database tables do have **rows** and **columns** - not fields or records - so I try to "nudge" programmers and newbies in that direction, yes - thanks for pointing out

Comment: @marc_s - I also tend to say columnname but I dont care when I edited the title I wrote columnname than noticed OP using fieldname in body and renamed it in title again :)

Comment: You can use `Regex.Replace` and regex like `(?<=\bTable\.)(\w+)(?=\b)`. Also there is no need to split your input to separate words. Though I'd agree with first comment in that it is doomed to fail if you accept arbitrary sql.

Comment: Hi.. well, its not total rewriting of the SQL query, but just replacing the TableName.ColumnName with some kind of identifier; rest of the SQL syntax stays intact.. Thanks for all your inputs!